# Unable to delete 90 days older data from mysql via shell script

Tags: mysql, bash, shell, centos

Below shell script : **error choose 3 1,2 it's OK but mysql delete success. shell script can't delete**

```
#!/bin/bash

selection=
until [ "$selection" = "0" ]; do
    echo "=============================="
    echo "=========PROGRAM MENU========="
    echo "1 - Show Date and Time"
    echo "2 - Show Data Database"
    echo "3 - Delete data 90 day ago"
    echo ""
    echo "0 - Back to command"
    echo "=============================="
    echo -n "Enter selection : "
    read selection
    echo ""

    case $selection in
        2 ) mysql -u [user] -p[password] -e  'USE eventime;SELECT date1,time1 FROM dt;' ;;
        1 ) dti=$(date '+%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S');
            echo "This is Date and Time : " $dti ;;
        3 ) DELETE FROM dt WHERE date1 <('SELECT STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(now(),'%Y-%m-%d'),'-1'),'%Y-%m-%d')- INTERVAL 90 DAY'); ;;
        0 ) Ctrl+Z ;;
        * ) echo "Please enter 1, 2, 3 or 0"
    esac
done
```

Output : Choose 3 : `SELECT STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(now(),%Y-%m-%d),-1),%Y-%m-%d)- INTERVAL 90 DAY: command not found...`

Comment: fix your errors in your script from http://www.shellcheck.net/, then try it once

Comment: And what's wrong with your script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script with errors. But you can user mysql script only, quite easy.
If you need to delete row, older(newer) than 90 days:

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(now(),'%Y-%m-%d'),'-1'),'%Y-%m-  %d')-INTERVAL 90 DAY;
```

Please check result, should by date you  need. If not, correct query.
So

```
delete from dt  where date1 >(SELECT STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(now(),'%Y-%m-%d'),'-1'),'%Y-%m-%d')-
INTERVAL 90 DAY);
```

Please be careful and read help for sql fuctions used in case of doubt.
Next time put output obtained, sofware versions and so on, so answers will be more exact.
Your bash script will contain shao-bao, licence information, and command mysql to execute query :) Good luck.

Comment: Thailand say : ขอบคุณครับ = thank you :)